# Matching sports-data from different sources

Tags: python, r

**Problem:** I am gathering data for football matches from different sources and I would like to compare it. The problem is that the sources have different formats, e.g.

```
"TSG Hoffenheim - Olympique Lyon"
"Hoffenheim - Lyon"
"1899 Hoffenheim - Olympique Lyonnais"
```

All of these correspond to the same event but I am uncertain how to efficiently match those events.

**Attempts:**

1. Using metrics (e.g. `stringdist`) could be an option: I have tested solutions of the form `stringdist(x,y,"jw") < epsilon`, where `epsilon` denotes a fixed threshold that I set and "jw" the chosen metric. However, this can lead to false matches of the sort

   ```
   "Atletico Madrid - Manchester City"
   "Real Madrid - Manchester United"
   ```

   where these correspond to two different events. There are some ways here to limit the false positives e.g. only comparing events from the same competition, occurring on the same date etc. but even this is not working perfectly.
2. Another possibility would be to create master files/functions used as references (list of clubs etc.). I already started with this but this is a very extensive manual labor which I would like to avoid if possible.

So far, all the testing that I have done was in `r` but if there convenient ways to tackle this problem in `python` I would gladly do so. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems very hard to solve automatically. How about creating a master file automatically and then deleting the wrong entries manually? Maybe upload a whole batch of your raw data so others can test with it

Comment: Just a question, why are you gathering infos from different sources, what's wrong with sofascore, flashscore or something similar. They all have plenty of infos about all teams/players/matches

Comment: @brainfuck4d That sounds interesting. Correct me if I'm wrong but it would require an initial list of clubs to match against right?

Comment: @DejanMaric So far I haven't found a source that provided all the data needed e.g. performances of team X before matchday Y.

Comment: I just thought, as you already have something that matches similar sounding clubs, that you could write these groups to file and then manually cross out the wrong clubs